# Using Auto Logout in YII2, Need to redirect user after login again to the same URL where user was before Auto Logout

Tags: php, session, yii2

My system Using YII2. System auto logout user after some time due to inactivity. As of now it redirect to main home page after login. But I need to redirect user to the same page where he/she was when system logout due to inactivity.

I tried to use YII2 return URL as well as session but session also gets destroyed when system logout the user.

I also need to keep user identity as it should redirect only when the same user login again in system after auto logout.

I tried YII2 return URL as well as session.

```
Yii::$app->user->returnUrl = someurl
```

Above line to save return url and to redirect to set URL

```
$url = Yii::$app->user->returnUrl;
return $this->goBack($url);
```

To redirect the user to previous URL but it doesn't work.

Also I need to identify the user, user should be same who got logout from the system due to inactivity, else it will redirect other user also to the previous URL who logged in first time.

Comment: The session should not be destroyed after logout by timeout. As you can see [in code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/User.php#L699) the logout is called with `false` as `$destroySession` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the `goBack()` method [does not takes any argument](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-controller#goBack()-detail). It uses the previously set `returnUrl` (like in your example).

Besides that the issue is that when you log out the user that will remove authentication-related session data. If `$destroySession` is true, all session data will be removed. And the `$destroySession` in the `logout()` method is `true` by default, so besides the authentication-related session data also the `returnUrl` data is removed.

Try to log out the user with the `$destroySession` parameter set to false:

```php
Yii::$app->user->logout(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `return $this->redirect(Yii::$app()->request->referrer);`

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: Referrer or referring page is the URL of the previous webpage. So Yii::$app()->request->referrer stores previous Yii2 page url. Redirect function will redirect to previous page.